# django FilterSet for end of day

Tags: django, datefilter

How to make the query take correct date from start date and end end of the day for FilterSet.
Now if you type start_filter_date = 2018.05.23 and end_filter_date = 2018.05.25. Then start_filter_date=2018.05.23T00:00 and end_filter_date=2018.05.25T00:00. Time is taken 00:00, but need to be 23:59?

My class is following:

```
class TaskFilterSet(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    id = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="pk")
    start_filter_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name="date_added", lookup_expr="gte")
    end_filter_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name="date_added", lookup_expr="lte")
```

Comment: i think the best way is use `gte` with `lt` but send end date + `timedelta(1)`

Comment: @BearBrown yes, but if front-side cann't do it. How to change on correct date on backend?

Comment: @BearBrown I am using generics for view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think the best way is use `gte` with `lt` but send end date `date_added + timedelta(1)`, i don't use the django filters but based on the [tips.html#solution-1-magic-values](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/tips.html#solution-1-magic-values) you can try:

```
class EndFilter(django_filters.DateFilter):

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value:
            value = value + timdelta(1)
        return super(EndFilter, self).filter(qs, value)


class TaskFilterSet(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):

    id = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="pk")
    start_filter_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name="date_added", lookup_expr="gte")
    end_filter_date = EndFilter(name="date_added", lookup_expr="lt")
```